# How do I find correct doxygen reference to things with complicated signatures?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am documenting some functions with template overloads and would want to reference to specific overloads. But I don't know how exactly to type the signature for the `\ref` command to understand; it unfortunately requires a canonical version and I don't know it. Is there a way to *get the list of canonical signatures doxygen generated?*

My specific case is function declared like this:

```
template <typename T, size_t S>
int function(T value, Table const (&descriptors)[S]);
```

I've tried

```
\ref function(T,Table(&)[])
\ref function<>(T,Table(&)[])
\ref function(T,const Table(&)[])
\ref function<>(T,const Table(&)[])
\ref function(T,Table const(&)[])
\ref function<>(T,Table const(&)[])
```

And I've tried without the `\ref` too (it's supposed to notice symbols automatically), but that was no better.

Or is there a *way to define the reference myself?*

I've also tried defining anchor in the target function documentation, but that points to the description body and not the header as reference to function should.

Comment: `S` should be part of the solution.

Answer (score 3):

A bug in doxygen prevented @ref'ing parameters whose type included braces.
I've just [committed](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/commit/1e373422387e8c1131f887efb47cf3da6459e2ac) a possible solution to GitHub. Let me know if that works for you.

I used the following example to test it myself:

```
/** @file */

/** complex function */
template <typename T, size_t S>
int function(T value, Table const (&descriptors)[S]);

/** @mainpage
 *  See @ref function(T,Table const (&)[S]) "complex function" for details.
 */
```